# Azure Synpase : How to trigger a sql when Scaling by sliding

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Azure Synpase : How to trigger a sql when Scaling by sliding .
SQL will collect information about application before scaling up or down

Let me know if possible

Comment: Azure synapse is scaled up or down  manually using slider bar , so my question is how to run a process that will execute  some sql before scaling up or down  Synapse

Answer (score 0):

You can script this and run processes before you scale up or down with powershell.

If you're capturing logs, you may be able to setup Azure functions that trigger on an event like scaling up or down.

Comment: Thanks for reply , appreciated. Do you know what could be the minimum logging that can be enabled to achieve the trigger of azure function

Comment: I wouldn't use the logging approach even if it's possible. Look into this doco with functions from MS, this will definitely be a much cheaper way to do what you're after: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/manage-compute-with-azure-functions